# Total partition of a sequence

Tags: combinatorics

From a sequence of size let say n consisting of numbers 1,2...n find the number of groups such that R and (R-1) will be in the same group if the sequence [1,2,3...N] is divided into group of "X" numbers sequentially i.e [1...N] is divided into groups [1...X],[(X+1)...2*X], [(2*X+1)...3*X] ... [ (X*floor((N-1)/X)+1)...N] , where 1<=X<=N and last group can have less than X numbers.

For eg: n=5 R=5
 For different values of "X" groups formed are as follow

For, X=1 ,
               [ {1},{2},{3},{4},{5} ]

```
     X=2
           [ {1,2} , {3,4} , {5} ]

     X=3
           [ {1,2,3} , {4,5} ]

     X=4
           [ {1,2,3,4} , {5} ]

     X=5
           [ {1,2,3,4,5} ]
```

We can clearly see that for X=3 and X=5, R and R-1 are in same groups.Hence answer=2.

Example 2:n=6 R=5
   X=1

```
           [ {1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6} ]

     X=2

           [ {1,2} , {3,4} , {5,6} ]

     X=3

           [ {1,2,3} , {4,5,6} ]

     X=4

           [ {1,2,3,4} , {5,6} ]

     X=5

           [ {1,2,3,4,5}, {6} ]

     X=6

           [ {1,2,3,4,5,6} ]
```

here ans=3 for X=3,5 and 6.

**Note:Can a formula be computed in general for this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When X divides R-1 then R and R-1 will be in separate blocks.  Otherwise I do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: thank you for your answer.so we need to calculate divisors of r-1 and that will involve prime factorization!